# Laptop battery suddenly drops to 0% & I have to recharge it

Tags: windows-8, laptop, battery, battery-life

I have a dell inspiron 3542. It's battery timing is 3-4 hours. But recently it started behaving weirdly. Battery suddenly drops to 0% and it turns off and doesn't start. I have to recharge to start it again. 
I thought it might be battery issue, so I got it replaced. The new one worked fine for a week or so. And now it's having the same issue. I'm a heavy Laptop user and can't go with this. Any thoughts or ideas on where's the fault? Or why is this issue happening? 
I have also reinstalled my windows to see if that was a software issue.

Comment: Check the embedded controller (if you can) that controls the charging process. Del support can help to troubleshoot

Comment: Don't know about embedded controller. Where can I get help? & Any idea of what's causing the issue?